# Do my Mutants having Chi/Spiritual/Magical/Supernatural powers undermined Religion and real-world beliefs?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, super-powers, supernatural, mutants

I'm writing a story about superpowers similar to the X Men, The Boys, and My Hero Academia. The powers are explained with science. That alone already undermine the supernatural. But that's not the biggest issue here. Magic doesn't always have to be supernatural in fiction. Magic can be science in fiction too. But the issue I have is can Magic be a generic mutation without undermining the concept of magic and the general opinion on magic.

Chi, Aura, Chakra, and Magic have all have one thing in common. They are all a natural life force that exists in all humans. That any human can tap into these sources. Most of the fiction follows that concept. Even in the real world, some people have this belief about spiritual forces. Myths and Legends say all these spiritual powers work this way. So it's hard to turn a natural life force any human can tap into a genetic mutation superpower. When the majority of fiction already has an unwritten rule that is back up by the real world and ancient myths.

Dr. Strange, Naruto, and Iron Fist would be considered biological mutants in my world. One of the biggest reasons I wanted to go this route. Because I wanted my world to be realistic. Like if magic exists and anyone can tap into the source of magic. But not everyone can do magic though (for obvious narrative story reasons cough cough muggles). Then why are there millions of Satanists, Wiccans, Pagans, and Voodoo believers around the world who can't do magic? If magic exists in your world. And you believe in magic. You are a part of a religion that believes in magic and studies magic. Then why can't you or 99 percent of your religion actually do magic/magick but a random atheist Doctor can ?

Which is why I said why not turn magic or any other spiritual power into biological mutant powers. That way it would explain why most people can't do magic or have these spiritual powers. Because they don't have the X gene or Meta gene to have those powers. Just how it was all Aliens this whole time. Angles and Gods were Aliens this whole time. In my world, it was Mutants this whole time. All the Witches/Wizards with their magical spells and Warrior Shaolin Monks with their super chi Kung Fu throughout history were just mutants who had the gene activated this whole time. And Religions and Hollywood Movies just associated certain psychic superpowers like Telekinesis and Telepathy with Wicca or Voodoo or any other magick-believing Religions.
This way the world feels more realistic. Because magic doesn't feel supernatural. It's just a belief some muggles have or an exaggerated mutant power associated with those muggle beliefs throughout history. It's like Christians don't get superpowers from reading Bible verses. Muslims don't get superpowers from reading the Quran too. So why can the same imply to magick believers too? The Wiccans don't actually get superpowers from practicing spells. Magic is just a pray to them. It's just a normal ritual. Wiccans are muggles just like how Christians are muggles. So Magic just feels like a natural realistic belief that is just tied to certain superpowers in history in this world.

But still, do I undermine the concept of Magic, Chi, Chakra, and Aura when I turn them into genetic mutations/ mutant superpowers?

Comment: So, conspiracy beliefs have proven that people can ignore science for their own belief (people who believe the earth is flat). Additionally, you need to take into account faith and its relationship with religion and beliefs (how people believe, even if they do not see). And if you are dealing with religious beliefs, be sure to be culturally and religiously sensitive. Do your research so you don't accidentally use misinformation.

Comment: By magic do you mean stuff that breaks physics? Mutations apply changes to an individual, but that individual still follows the laws of physics.

Comment: I think it is a good question, but your wording is very confusing. I wonder if you could edit a bit for clarity. Or maybe add a list of world properties, so it is easier to understand the rules of your world.

Comment: You're writing a story about your own fictional world, not about the real world. I see no reason why You can't say superhuman abilities with a pseudo-magic genetic background (because I'm pretty sure a random special gene isn't nearly enough to realistically explain why little Timmy can crush people into flesh balls with the power of his mind) were explained throughout history as magic, the act of spiritual forces or miracles, therefore influencing said beliefs to begin with.

Comment: @ProjectApex The question is not whether the OP can use DNA mutation as an explanation for supernatural abilities. The OP states that they already do that. The question asks how this (supernatural abilities are the result of genetic mutations) would affect religions and notions of supernatural abilities.

Comment: @Otkin and the answer is "however you see fit", since the effects that could result in alterations to these religions and beliefs technically already happened. Whether these would only strengthen these beliefs and religions or leave doubts is up to them to decide according to what story they want to tell. For an example, look at how in Jojo's bizarre adventure the story equivalent of Jesus was essentially a powerful "stand user", yet the faith around it seems very similar to catholicism (except for one priest that adores a vampiric crossfit demigod in part 6).

Comment: @ProjectApex 'However you see fit' is the answer to almost any question on this stack if the world's creator does not care about realism. However, if realism is a goal then possible scenarios start to rapidly decrease in number. Psychological realism is also a thing. People are not perfectly rational beings and it is often not possible to describe them with neat maths. But it does not mean that they and their reactions, especially group reactions, are unpredictable. Religions and beliefs don't appear and don't change randomly. They follow specific patterns.

Comment: @ProjectApex IMO, 'you can tell whatever story you want to tell' is a true statement, but it is one of the worst approaches to the questions on this stack. This is not why people come here and this is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Otkin indeed it is not, which is why I myself have asked questions here over the plausibility of certain anatomical traits rather than just assuming they worked. This question however, as far as I see, is much more centered around events within the story and their repercussions on beliefs that exist within the world, and as unsatisfying as it may be, in this specific case whether there are or not changes is mostly dependent on what the writer wants,which is probably one of the reasons it was deemed as opinion based.

Answer (score 10):

Assumption: the powers you describe are real and explainable with science, just like any power source we're currently aware of.

Given the above, the short answer to your question is **OBVIOUSLY NO**.

**Two claims require addressing:**
People will believe whatever they want to believe, so if "magic" becomes a mundane power there will still be people who believe in "magic" and maybe even try to do it ritualistically.

I can only speak from a Christian perspective, but as far as your claims go:

- *explained with science. That alone already undermine the supernatural*

This one is obviously faulty. The universe as Christianity has understood it for the last 20 centuries, with the exceptions of the weirdest, most backward, science denying denominations, is a fundamentally understandable place. We live in a rational universe: we can choose any object and any phenomenon, observe it, hypothesise about it and come to rational and repeatable conclusions about it. Whether it's lightning (on Earth or on some other planet), whether it's geological forces, quasars, black holes, gender, photosynthesis, brain chemistry, evolution, cosmology, we can set aside emotion, set aside mythology, collect the facts and see what they reveal to us about the universe.

All you are doing is adding a couple new facts to an already established as rational universe. This not only will not undermine the supernatural (because the supernatural -- God, angels, etc -- is by definition outside of the natural order), but can not undermine it. If anything, your additions will simply pass unnoticed, at least to the Christian. As the powers are demythologised and understood in rational terms, the underlying rationality of the universe and its Creator are simply revealed just a little bit more.

- *Christians don't get superpowers from reading Bible verses*

This is actually not entirely true. Sure, we don't get spiffy costumes or other mundane superpowers like the ability to fly or bounce bullets off our bracelets or leap tall buildings with a single bound. We only get supernatural superpowers. Myeh.

**Conclusion:**
As far as rational Christianity is concerned, the powers you describe will have absolutely zero effect on the faith. Just as with heliocentrism and evolution, there will be irrational Christians who just can't get with the programme. They don't understand that science is actually a method of divine revelation and they don't understand that the Church has been pro-science since its inception (beginning with the sciences of philosophy and theology). But the goal of the Christian religion isn't to learn how superpowers work, so they wouldn't really matter anyway.

As far as other religions are concerned, I doubt that Judaism or Islam or Zoroastrianism or Jainism or Shinto will be affected either. People who follow these very old religions have lived in the same rational world where the superpowers you describe have long existed.

As far as the magic-believing religions you mention (Wicca, Neopaganisms, etc), I honestly don't think they would even be affected really. These movements are new, arising in the 19th century. Surely Aleister Crowley et al would have been as aware of these superpowers as they were of electricity & gravity & magnetism. It could be that such religions would be fundamentally different to the ones we're familiar with in the primary world. They might arise as a means of seeking to harness those powers, though without realising the genetic component. Later prophets, later gurus would continue to seek and would continue to make a fortune selling their secrets. Adherents and followers will always be drawn by the possibilities of accessing this "magic", even though there is already a perfectly rational scientific explanation for what it is and how it works.

Answer (score 3):

**Science and religion come from a whole other way of thinking**

Sciencecand religion are fundamentally different. So different they can be practiced at the same time. There are still plenty of religious people on this Earth that are also highly regarded scientists. Even during my university time you could see that there were plenty of religious people about in many student associations. Science does not exclude religion.

Religious people can also be very rational. Imagine a flat Earther and a normal person. It doesn't matter what one believes or the other, the fact is that we live on a round Earth. The atheist Doctor Strange might not believe, but that doesn't matter for the believer. The good Doctor's belief will not make gods disappear or not make him be able to do miracles. He can be an instrument of the religion, regardless what he believes.

Even if it has scientific explanations, it can still be magical or spiritual. Even now lightning, storms or floods are relatively well understood and predictable, yet there's many that still attribute these to gods and spirits.

If it doesn't have scientific explanations, all religious and spiritual hell beeaks loose, metaphorically speaking.

*Conclusion*

Religion might be more difficult in a scientific age, but it's still very much around. It doesn't matter what others believe. It matters what *they* believe.

Answer (score 3):

You ask two slightly different questions, so I will address both of them.

*1. Do my Mutants having Chi/Spiritual/Magical/Supernatural powers undermined Religion and real-world beliefs?* The short answer to this is **no**.

If anything, these abilities strengthen religion since they serve as proof that something beyond the material world exists. There is no longer any need to engage in lengthy discussions: Miracles are already real.

Religions focus on two things: 1. The Origin/Source of all (in the broadest sense, not limited to creation stories) and 2. Life ethics/life philosophy.

The Origin is the power behind all rules of the universe, it is an attempt to explain why these rules are 'fixed'. Religions can try to study and explain the specific rules but since it is not their primary goal they are flexible and can assimilate explanations provided by other approaches, for example, science. A slightly different notion of a specific rule does not undermine the existence of the Origin, it just highlights the mystery and beauty of God's work (if you are a follower of a monotheistic religion) or the boundlessness of Dao (if you are a Daoist) or whatever else you have faith in.

When it comes to ethics and life philosophy, knowledge of physics (or any other science) does not affect them at all: Morals are arbitrary rules. They can be justified or rationalised somehow, but it is not truly necessary. The only thing that is needed is a belief that this particular way is the right way. Everything else is just an attempt to make this belief look better (more rational, or more logical, or more 'natural', pick your poison).

As for real-world beliefs, they will also be strengthened. It will no longer be possible to dismiss myths as a pure fantasy since magic- and Qi-users, supernatural and spiritual forces are real, objectively and provably exist in this world.

The common sense (or commonly accepted 'truths'), of course, will be different from our world. How different depends on the world's history and prevalence of supernatural powers and their users. But one thing you can be sure of is that no one will doubt the existence of something beyond the material world. They might define it using different words, but the notion that it is real will be a part of common sense.

*2. do I undermine the concept of Magic, Chi, Chakra, and Aura when I turn them into genetic mutations/ mutant superpowers?* This short answer to this is also **no**.

Divine is mysterious. Anything or anyone can be chosen to become a divine tool. There is no requirement for cooperation or faith. One does not ask their tools whether they want to complete user's tasks or believe in their users. Tools are simply being used, it is their only purpose. A random atheist Doctor is such a tool. It is being used to achieve a specific goal. The divine does not concern itself with the tool's thoughts on the subject.

There is also no specific, set-in-stone method of the said tool activation. DNA mutation is no more undermining for the concept of Qi than the idea of 'spiritual roots' popular in xianxia (Eastern fantasy). Some people have the capability and some people don't. It does not really matter why. Talent, DNA, bloodline, or divine blessing are equally suitable explanations.

Answer (score 0):

### Proving the Unprovable:

The obvious problem is that our current understanding of physics is incompatible with people having the ability to manipulate the fundamental laws of physics by will and genes alone. So to explain these things scientifically, you need to make some pretty extreme alterations to how we understand reality, including the underlying assumptions that some fairly pseudo-mystic stuff is real.

For readers, I think suspension of disbelief will cover it. But even having scientific explanations for these things won't really undermine them as magic, because the explanations AREN'T going to be hard-scientific. Endless stories have psychic abilities, magic-science hybrids, and the like without much problem. This is not to say, however, that there won't be effects on belief.

I have some similar powers in a similar world. In this world, there are extradimensional beings that are lured into doing the alteration for the benefit of humans - basically, humans are the bait for bored entities that exist in additional external dimensions to our own. Things are conserved to the extent that matter and energy come from elsewhere, and physics is accounted for with additional dimensions.

While such an approach will compensate for the differences, it is far from being compatible with hard science, and requires entities from outside our 'reality' to be available to alter it (gods/spirits/ghosts/demons).

Such beings might cause a serious challenge to several modern religions, but actually many ancient faiths already assume the existence of such entities or powers. Religion is all about providing an explanation for things science can't. The problem comes when these beings don't behave in ways consistent with those faiths (demons are not driven out by exorcisms, ancient gods exist and do stuff for worshippers, etc.) While in my version, the various faiths have had centuries to work through the consequences, in your world these things will be new and concrete. But most have some background to explain them (the stuff we tend to ignore today).

So you need to be acutely aware HOW your super-powers work, and HOW each faith might interpret those things. For example, a faith might accept those abilities as real, but automatically ascribe them to witchcraft. So it would be no challenge to the faith, but could be a challenge to how those faiths relate to those with the powers.

It will also significantly affect how people with these powers interact with them. A person could interpret their abilities as Satanic, and assume if they use them that their soul is compromised. They might then refrain from using their gifts or alternatively embrace evil and lose their moral compass. They could believe they are calling on saints and angels, interpreting their gifts as divine and becoming deeply faithful, while smiting anyone who doesn't live up to their standards.

So while I don't think the faiths will be challenged by the powers, I think your users will be deeply affected by the religious implications of them.

Comment: The OP states: *Just how it was all Aliens this whole time. Angles and Gods were Aliens this whole time. In my world, it was Mutants this whole time. All the Witches/Wizards with their magical spells and Warrior Shaolin Monks with their super chi Kung Fu throughout history were just mutants who had the gene activated this whole time.*  It seems that magic/supernatural always existed in the world, it is not something new.

Comment: @Otkin Even if it was always mutants, people have always interpreted it as magic/aliens/gods etc. so my point is that people would still view the powers through the lenses that they have for centuries (even if somehow science seems to provide an explanation).  The interpretation of these will vary depending on what lens those faiths use. The "new" is people manifesting this stuff in a modern scientific world in a provable fashion.

Comment: Key take-away: whenever you (or any of us!) thinks to begin their WB response with *"The obvious problem is that our current understanding of physics is incompatible with..."* the respondent's immediate next step should be to pause and remind herself what forum this is. This isn't the Physics forum. This is Worldbuilding. A fundamental truth of the OP's world is that people ***can in fact do things we find incompatible with physics***.  Or job isn't to complain that the fictional world isn't real enough. Our job is to approach the fictional world as it is and work from there!

Comment: @elemtilas Your message seems a bit angry. In this specific case, the OP is asking about the scientific validation of what is essentially magic and the effects it would have on the belief in essentially magical belief systems. MY point was that if you were going against current science but claiming science, the explanation of HOW was important to this question. If I was being petty or on the Physics SE, I'd be downvoting the question, possibly the answers, and vote to close (which I did not).

Comment: @DWKraus -- Oh, not at all! It's just that so many respondents couch their answers in that way. It's kind of become ridiculous that I find myself reminding well respected and long time members that the basis for this forum is *fiction*. OP may be asking about "scientific validation", but that science comes from within a fictional context! If I were on Physics, I'd be downvoting it too! Simply because of what you said in your answer! Certainly I apologise if I came across as angry. Just a little frustrated with the reality bias that crops up. If the OP had specified a "hard science" tag...

Comment: @DWKraus ... or had specified that the fictional world's science is *exactly the same as in the real world*, then I wouldn't have said anything at all. Also, I probably wouldn't have answered the question myself and possibly would have voted to close due to lack of clarity.